# How do I make the background in a tkinter window transparent?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make this so the window background is transparent, but the image remains visible?

Here is my code;

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Canvas
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width = 300, height = 300)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Sprites/ph1.png"))
        self.canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=self.image)
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("+1630+775")
root.overrideredirect(1)
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what system ? on Linux it can't set transparent background. You would have to use different GUI instead of `tkinter` - ie. `PyQt`

Comment: Using `master.title("A simple GUI")` while `.overrideredirect(1)` is contradict.

Comment: Which OS? windows, osx and linux have quite different approaches. Please also provide a link to your image as not every png works.

Comment: Pick on of [`[python][tkinter] transparent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+transparent)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not provided the requested information about the OS used to allow for a useful answer.